# vaadin combo box does not render scrolbar in iOS/iPAD mobile browsers

Tags: ios, ipad, vaadin7

we are using vaadin combo box - http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler-for-vaadin6#ComboBoxStartsWith.

when accessed from iPAD / iOS safari browser,it is not showing the scroll bar. and unable to navigate to items in the bottom of the item eg example country list

Any suggest to overcome this issue

Comment: ComboBox doesn't have scrollbars on the popup just buttons to jump previous/next page

Comment: Thanks Henri, One way is use NativeSelect. However, it does not have filtering option.